# R:Summing up values of a column row by row and create new column

Tags: r

i have the following column

```
1
0
0
1
1
1
```

and i want a new column with the sum of the values row by row wo something like this

```
1 1
0 1
0 1
1 2
1 3
1 4
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `cumsum`

```
> x <- c(1,0,0,1,1,1)
> x
[1] 1 0 0 1 1 1
> cumsum(x)
[1] 1 1 1 2 3 4
```

Putting altogether

```
> cbind(x, xsum=cumsum(x))
     x xsum
[1,] 1    1
[2,] 0    1
[3,] 0    1
[4,] 1    2
[5,] 1    3
[6,] 1    4
```